# Error in Append From VFP OLEDB in C#

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro

I try to append delimited text to a `Fox` table with this code:

```
OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(String.Format(@"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source={0};Collating Sequence=MACHINE", Inputpath + "UnRepWor.dbf"));
OleDbCommand oledbComm = new OleDbCommand { Connection = oledbConn, CommandType = CommandType.Text };

string insertCammand = String.Format(@"APPEND FROM {0} DELIMITED WITH TAB", @"'d:\TestServiceOutput\data.dat'");
oledbComm.CommandText = insertCammand.Trim();
try
{
   oledbConn.Open();
   oledbComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw Utility.GetExceptionDetails(ex, "WordRootFoxExportServiceDataAccessLayer - ImportToFoxTable- insert into Fox Table",ex.Message);
}
```

and get this Error:

```
Message = "One or more errors occurred during processing of command."
Source  = "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro"
ErrorCode = -2147217900
ex.StackTrace :
    at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)    
    at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
    at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although your existing code is buggy, I don't think Append from is directly supported via VFPOLEDB. Instead you can try like this:

```
string vfpScript = string.Format(@"
use UnRepWor shared
APPEND FROM ('{0}') DELIMITED WITH TAB
use", @"d:\TestServiceOutput\data.dat");

using (OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(String.Format(@"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source={0};Collating Sequence=MACHINE", Inputpath)))
{
  OleDbCommand oledbComm = new OleDbCommand { 
    Connection = oledbConn, 
    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, 
    CommandText="ExecScript" };
  oledbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("code", vfpScript);

  try
  {
    oledbConn.Open();
    oledbComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     throw Utility.GetExceptionDetails(ex,
       "WordRootFoxExportServiceDataAccessLayer - ImportToFoxTable- insert into Fox Table", 
      ex.Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, as I was afraid of, it is not supported via VFPOLEDB although it is listed in supported commands. It may work from within a stored procedure.

Comment: To workaround you can read your tab delimited file with ACE or JET driver and insert into VFP table.